# Issue with `int` vs. `double` - why isn't my program working?

Tags: c++, int, double, mingw, codeblocks

I have just started teaching myself C++ after 2+ years of working with MATLAB and wanting something a little more robust. I am currently using code::blocks with MinGW I am trying to get the hang of using `int` and `double`, but for some reason my little test program won't work.

The program was a way for me to practice using functions. The program takes in numbers from the user and stops when a negative number is inserted. Then, it spits out the sum of the input numbers, product of input numbers, and a count of the numbers processed.

When I use only `int`, the program works as intended, but can't handle any "decimal" numbers thrown at it - it freaks out.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int X;
int sum;
int product;

int SUM()
{
    int A = sum+X;
    sum = A;
}

int PRODUCT()
{
    int B=product*X;
    product = B;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"Welcome to my counting program! "<<endl;
    sum = 0;
    product = 1;
    int counter = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        cout<<"Give me a number: ";
        cin>>X;
        if (X<0)
        {
            break;
        }
        sum = SUM();
        product = PRODUCT();
        counter = counter+1;
    }

    cout<<"SUM: ";
    cout<< sum <<endl;
    cout<<"PRODUCT: ";
    cout<< product <<endl;
    cout<<"NUMBERS INPUT: ";
    cout<< counter <<endl;

    system ("PAUSE");
}
```

However, when I use double where applicable, the program only gives me zeroes for the product and sum.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

double X;
double sum;
double product;

int SUM()
{
    double A = sum+X;
    sum = A;
}

int PRODUCT()
{
    double B=product*X;
    product = B;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"Welcome to my counting program! "<<endl;
    sum = 0.0;
    product = 1.0;
    double counter = 0.0;

    for (;;)
    {
        cout<<"Give me a number: ";
        cin>>X;
        if (X<0)
        {
            break;
        }
        sum = SUM();
        product = PRODUCT();
        counter = counter+1;
    }

    cout<<"SUM: ";
    cout<< sum <<endl;
    cout<<"PRODUCT: ";
    cout<< product <<endl;
    cout<<"NUMBERS INPUT: ";
    cout<< counter <<endl;

    system ("PAUSE");
}
```

What am I doing wrong? what do I need to change to make it work?

Also, I think I am calling my functions incorrectly and trying to pass values between them incorrectly - what is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still returning int from your functions.  Also, since you're assigning the results, you need to return an appropriate value (`sum = SUM();`).

Try the following changes:

```
double /*int*/ SUM()
{
    double A = sum+X;
    sum = A;
    return sum; // Return a value!
}

double /*int*/ PRODUCT()
{
    double B=product*X;
    product = B;
    return product; // Return a value!
}
```

I would also recommend avoiding the globals for `sum`/`product`/`X`, and instead declare them local to your functions, and pass them as arguments to your methods.

Comment: Thank you very much! That fix worked! 

However I'm still pondering the part where you said "avoiding the globals for sum/product/X, and instead declare them local to your functions, and pass them as arguments to your methods." How should I do that in terms of my program?

Comment: @SergeantLuno Make your methods like:  `double Sum(double a, double b)`, then pass IN "sum" and "X", and return the sum, setting to sum.  This allows you to get rid of the global variables entirely.